# UI router changing URL but not changing template / controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent / child scheme set up with ui router and I just can't seem to get it to "go". throws no errors, and seems to conform to the examples.

app.config.js: under the `$stateProvider`

```
    .state('customers', {
      url:'/customers',
      templateUrl: 'app/customers/customers.html',
      controller: 'customerCtrl'
    })
    .state('customers.detail', {
    url: '/:id',
    parent: 'customers',
    templateUrl: 'app/customers/detail/detail.html',
    controller: 'customerDetail'
    })
```

I have those two routes.

customerCtrl.js:

```
$scope.rowDblClick = function(row){
    $state.go('customers.detail', {id: row.entity.customer_id})
}
```

and that in my `ui-grid` function for double clicking.  I can get it to load not being a child route, but as a child it's very angry.

```
<div ui-view>
     <div class="routeHeader">
       Customer Listing
     </div>
     <button class="button-small newCustomer" ng-click="newCustomer()">New Customer</button>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 cols" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection>

       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: have u added <ui-view> in your customers.html ?

Comment: Thanks, I just did that, and it appears to work, but the back button no longer gets me back to the previous /customers route.  it still shows the /id route

Comment: good job mark my answer is accepted. and for back button or history you have to enable htmls mode.

Comment: Can you still give a hand with the customers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<ui-view >` in your customers.html file.